# User is not authorized to create topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection

Tags: ldap, activemq-classic, shiro

I'm trying to implement LDAP based authentication and authorization in ActiveMQ.

The LDAP part is done with ApacheDS 2.0. (Structure taken from http://tmielke.blogspot.com/2011/12/activemq-ldap-based-authentication-and.html - unfortunately the referenced FuseSource ActiveMQ Security Guide is offline)

I created the users (e.g. uid=user2,ou=users,o=X) as inetOrgPerson with a SHA userPassword.
The ou=system looks like this:

[image: LDAP ActiveMQ structure]

The ldif of the selected element is:

```
dn: cn=admin,cn=ActiveMQ.\>,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,ou=ActiveMQ,ou=system
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: admin
member: ou=users,o=X
member: uid=user2,ou=users,o=X
```

(I tried with only one of the member and with both)

The shiro.ini is referenced from the plugins part of activemq.xml with:

```
<bean id="shiroPlugin" class="org.apache.activemq.shiro.ShiroPlugin" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <property name="iniResourcePath" value="classpath:shiro.ini"/>
</bean>
```

and contains only the following entry in the [main] part:

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=users,o=X
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://localhost:10389
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm
```

The authentication is working from Java:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
AuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordToken("user2", "password123");
AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = securityManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
System.out.println("authenticationInfo: " + authenticationInfo);
//authenticationInfo: user2
```

However, when connecting to the MoM-Broker and trying to send a Message I get the following Exception:

```
SecurityException: Subject [user2] is not authorized to create destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection
```

How can I grant this user to create the destination topic? ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093799/activemq-user-is-not-authorized-to-create-topic-activemq-advisory-connection) rather old question did not help)